# Meteor problems after 1.0.3.1 update

Tags: javascript, meteor

Yesterday I ran `meteor update` and updated to 1.0.3.1 and it broke what I was working on.

I'm not sure what broke, but even the hello world project that ships with meteor is broken. When I do:

```
meteor create test
cd test
meteor run
```

I get these errors:

```
minimongo.js:3193 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

ddp.js:3557 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

follower-livedata.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined

application-configuration.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined

mongo.js:1000 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

autoupdate.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined

livedata.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined

observe-sequence.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LocalCollection' of undefined

blaze.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObserveSequence' of undefined

ui.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined

templating.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined

spacebars.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined

global-imports.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined

template.test.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined

test.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
```

The `test.js:5` points here:

```
(function(){if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({ // <-error here
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });
```

I don't understand why this is causing an error.

The .html reads:

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

which looks fine but maybe I am missing something.

---

UPDATE:

What I have tried so far:

I ran `rm -rf .meteor` then ran `meteor rebuild` and I got:

```
this is your first time using Meteor! Installing a Meteor distribution in your home directory.
######################################################################## 100.0%
Packages rebuilt.
```

which sounded good so I ran `meteor run`:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

<del>and still got the same errors.</del> actually looks like it works!

Comment: What happens if you do `meteor --release 1.0.2.1` in your project? Does it run?

Comment: Possibly a corrupt file. Backup your files and package list - wipe meteor - try again. It's failing on the standard-packages and not your code. I don't think this is something you did (other than update).. I could be wrong

Comment: Hi. `meteor --release 1.0.2.1` downgrades a lot of packages but I still get the same error.

Comment: Also, I tried to nuke meteor and start over but I am still getting the same problems. I ran `rm -rf /usr/local/meteor /usr/local/bin/meteor` and then `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh` but no luck.

Comment: Meteor data is stored in `~/.meteor`  try wiping out that directory. Also, try `meteor rebuild`

Comment: Hi, that worked. If you want to leave it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!